# Javascript File Not Found, File extension has %22 Added for No Reason?

Tags: javascript, path, wamp

I am using both a WAMP server and my school server, I have some Javascript but it refuses to run, looking into Mozilla Firefox's debugger the best I've been able to determine is that it either can't find or access the file.

On the WAMP side of things I get "Forbidden" when it tries to poke at it:

```
[00:53:56.653] GET local_host/MyUserName%27s%20Homepage/japanese/js/myjs.js%22   
[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 1ms]
```

If I use my school server it says "Not Found":

```
[01:09:26.683] GET http://users.faculty.myschool.ca/~myusername/japanese/testing.js%22  
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 30ms]
```

However I can verify the file itself is very much where it should be, but however:

```
[01:09:26.782] GET http://users.faculty.myschool.ca/~myusername/japanese/images/kiniro-  
mosaic.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 21ms]
```

I notice there's a %22 for the file its trying to find, versus not there for something it DOES find, best I can figure out.

I've been trying to recreate the file and stuff but as far as windows is concerned, valud JS file...?

Comment: %22 if I am not wrong is the " character. Do you have a " character extra at the end?

Comment: The extra character is probably in the HTML script tag, not the js.

Comment: Really weird, I am sure in my earlier iterations my '"' was proper, "js/myjs.js", looking now though this doesn't appear to be the case. So I fixed it and now it appears to work, I'll set this as answered; I swear that typo didn't exist when the problem first appeared, I don't understand. :( Sorry for wasting your times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to have been a typo, I am just as confused as any of you.

Comment: Had this problem, it's an escaped quote (") mark. I found that my php var was using single quotes to encapsulate a variable, but in the href of a link I accidentally escaped the double quotes around it, so the url started with \"page.php. Removed the escape slash and it worked.